# Flutter Firebase firestore .data[""] error

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase "**cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3+1**" with my flutter app and ım traying to get data from firebase, but ..data["name] code not working. how can I fix that?

[image]

```
 Widget searchList(){
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: searchSnapshot.docs.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index){
      return SearchTile(
        userName: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data["name"],
        userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data["email"],
      );
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this. you need to call data()['fieldName']

```
  return SearchTile(
    userName: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["name"],
    userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["email"],
  );
```